# single cell rna seq-QC removing cells with high mitochondrial reads

Tags: r, genome, seurat

I am working with a non model organism which has an annotated reference genome and a seperate mitochondrial genome as both fasta and gtf files in ncbi. The mitochondrial genes are not of part of the reference genome and I was wondering how I can go about identifying the cells with high mitochondrial reads in seurat. I usually only align my reads (not using 10x genomics) to the reference genome and do the downstream analysis on seurat. Should I somehow combine the mt genes into the reference?

Would appreciate your help if anyone have suggestions.

Thank you

```
data.filt <- data.filt[!grepl("^MT-", rownames(data.filt)), ]
```

Comment: Mitochondrial genes need to be included in the reference so that the reads originating from them can be aligned. You didn't mention which aligner you use, but some aligners allow you to specify several fasta files when you build the reference. Otherwise you have to combine the genomic and mitochondrial references.